# Как спарсить и сопоставить данные из txt (погода косм)?

Tags: java, парсер, xmlparser

**Описание**
Есть данные о погода в космосе, размещены на ftp, в формате txt, текст закодирован. Инструкция декодирования имеется.
В программировании я еще слабоват, поэтому для представления решения, проектирую его пока.

1.1.Выделил что нужен:
класс для парсинга
класс хранения данных о космической погоде и ее последующего отображения.

**Алгоритм работы**

1. Обращается на ftp
2. Загружает txt файл
3. Извлекает данные из txt
4. сопоставляем (декодирует) данные (пример: если ключевое слово AFRED, то смотрим значение....)
5. Сопоставленные (Декодированные) данные помещает в соответствующую переменную класса SunWeather (Пример: Ар в ТипДанных, 10 в Значение, дата в ДатаВыпускаТелеграммы и т.д.)
   6.Класс SunWeather по запросу пользователя отображает данные

**Вопросы:**

- подскажите пожалуйста, как спарсить данные с txt?
- как перевести спарсенные (декодирование, сопоставление) данные в нормальный читаемый вид? Пример: 
  в файле указано
  AKRT 2906 5
  Это значит, т.е. переводит в "читаемый вид":
  АК - Тип Ак
  Дата 29.06.
  Значение 5

Значит наверное надо класс для хранения данных для сопоставления? Так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извлечь данные из txt файла довольно-таки просто. 
Один из вариантов, которым сам пользовался и в гуглится в интернете:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Вместо file.txt указываете полный путь до файла. А вместо *StringBuilder* я бы использовал массив строк (если размер txt известен), либо *ArrayList*. Но это только в том случае, если данные в файле построчные. Если же они разделены не новыми строками, а просто какими то символами, то тогда функция *split()* Вам поможет.
А для декодирования, вероятно, следует создать класс(как правильно было замечено), в котором будут храниться всевозможные варианты "информации", и так же в этом классе методы для получения элемента из массива, который спарсили из txt файла, затем для сравнения с имеющимися образцами (тут, скорее всего, без *split()* тоже не обойтись), и затем удаления декодированной строки, чтобы не занимала место.

Comment: В классе Files есть более интересные вещи: Files.newBufferedReader(), Files.readAllLines()

Comment: Спасибо большое! А спарсенные и обработанные данные передать в класс для хранения и последующего отображения данных, методом из класса ТХТпарсер?

Comment: Я не очень понял вопрос, но если его суть в том, как передать данные из одного класса в другой, то можно не методом, а просто обратившись к переменной класса, в которой хранится уже обработанная информация.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр перефразирую вопрос. На примере, Класс парсер парсит данные из ТХТ. Хранит в переменной String распарсенный текст (спасибо за вопрос ;)! да, текст телеграммы нам нужен).   2. Далее, как класс для сопоставления (декодирования) осуществит  сопоставление? Получается класс для сопоставления не нужен? Просто нужно в классе Парсер написать метод сопоставления? Так? как считаете, подскажите пожалуйста.  
Примеры:
AKFF 2606 5 2806

F2 2606 5 

где, АК - это Тип элемента
2606 - это дата 26.06.2018
5 - это значение
2806 - это дата на которую прогнозируется явление.

Comment: Если данные поставляются одинакового вида, то проблем вообще не должно возникнуть. Парсером Вы в `ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();` записываете всю информацию из txt файла. Затем, в классе Decoder обращаетесь к своему arraylist'у типа `String 
 info = Parser.text.get(0);`, например для получения первого элемента. И затем делите эту строчку на подстроки методом `split(" ");`. Тем самым вы получитепо отдельности каждый элемент строки. Или же есть функция, которая вычленяет нужную подстроку из строки **String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)**. Надеюсь, я правильно Вас понял

Comment: А для сравнения того, какая информация пришла с тем, что есть в классе декодера и выбирать нужную "маску", Вам могут помочь регулярные выражения.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр использовал код. Но данные не отбираются выходит ошибка. Модете помочь, посмотреть в чем причина?

Comment: @МишаковАлександр скрин приложил к описанию основной задачи

Comment: @Kirumit, Ваша ошибка вероятнее всего связана с тем,что класс не закрыт {[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934412/java-compile-error-reached-end-of-file-while-parsing)} По ссылке описано,в чем проблема. А вообще, на Вашем месте я бы просто сделал так: sb.append("\n"); вместо lineSeparator()